# Отображение финансовых (биржевых) данных в виде японских свечей

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

У меня есть датасет сигнатуры (GMT  Open    High    Low Close   Volume) цен валютной пары.
Может быть есть готовые решения (библиотеки или код для plt) для прорисовки этих данных в виде японских свеч?

Вот pd.head():

```
0   05.05.2003;00:00:00.000 1.12161 1.12314 1.12154 1.12258 29914.8008
1   05.05.2003;01:00:00.000 1.12232 1.12262 1.12099 1.12140 28370.6992
2   05.05.2003;02:00:00.000 1.12141 1.12211 1.12085 1.12152 29867.6992
3   05.05.2003;03:00:00.000 1.12123 1.12179 1.12049 1.12162 27256.8008
4   05.05.2003;04:00:00.000 1.12098 1.12176 1.12079 1.12122 28278.9004
```

Answer (score 2):

Воспользуйтесь модулем [mpl_finance](https://github.com/matplotlib/mpl_finance).

[Пример](https://github.com/matplotlib/mpl_finance/blob/master/examples/finance_demo.py):

```
import datetime

import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib.dates import MONDAY, DateFormatter, DayLocator, WeekdayLocator

from mpl_finance import candlestick_ohlc  #  pip install mpl-finance

date1 = "2004-2-1"
date2 = "2004-4-12"


mondays = WeekdayLocator(MONDAY)        # major ticks on the mondays
alldays = DayLocator()              # minor ticks on the days
weekFormatter = DateFormatter('%b %d')  # e.g., Jan 12
dayFormatter = DateFormatter('%d')      # e.g., 12

quotes = pd.read_csv('data/yahoofinance-INTC-19950101-20040412.csv',
                     index_col=0,
                     parse_dates=True,
                     infer_datetime_format=True)

# select desired range of dates
quotes = quotes[(quotes.index >= date1) & (quotes.index <= date2)]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
fig.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.2)
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mondays)
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(alldays)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(weekFormatter)
# ax.xaxis.set_minor_formatter(dayFormatter)

# plot_day_summary(ax, quotes, ticksize=3)
candlestick_ohlc(ax, zip(mdates.date2num(quotes.index.to_pydatetime()),
                         quotes['Open'], quotes['High'],
                         quotes['Low'], quotes['Close']),
                 width=0.6)

ax.xaxis_date()
ax.autoscale_view()
plt.setp(plt.gca().get_xticklabels(), rotation=45, horizontalalignment='right')

plt.show()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: у меня при выполнении этого кода ошибка: ` candlestick_ohlc(ax, zip(mdates.date2num(quotes.index.to_pydatetime()),
AttributeError: 'Index' object has no attribute 'to_pydatetime'`, Подскажете в чем проблема?

Comment: @Mavar, не могу воспроизвести эту ошибку. Какую версию Pandas вы используете?

Comment: вот этот блокнот: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1jRaO-1ho4peuzzA7VUNkdupDFBmCb6Z9

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas
import mplfinance as mpf
import matplotlib
import yfinance as yf
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.figure(figsize=(26,18))
msft=yf.Ticker('MSFT')
msft1=msft.history(period="1mo") #  1d, 5d, 1mo, 3mo, 6mo, 1y, 2y, 5y, 10y, ytd, max
%matplotlib inline
mpf.plot(msft1,type='candle')
plt.style.use('fivethirtyeight')
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]